# Consuming my custom WCF LOB adapter

Tags: c#, wcf, biztalk, biztalk-2013, wcf-lob-adapter

My question is: Why is the consuming wcf adapter dialog is not updated, when I change my code and build new dll and put it into the GAC?

Details: I am developing my custom wcf lob adapter for Biztalk server 2013 r2. I have implemented needed interfaces and `IMetadataBrowseHandler`, then built it and put it into the GAC.

When consuming it in a Biztalk project, I can see my results when going through the "Add Generated Items=>ConsumeAdapterService". I change my code, so I must see new nodes in the tree but I did not see any new item until I restart Visual Studio.

Here is the picture of the dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time your Visual Studio loads the DLL from the local GAC. The second time (after you have updated it), the DLL is already part of your application domain so it will not be updated unless you restart Visual Studio.

This is the default behavior which is pretty much standard within .NET.

You cannot say to Visual Studio something in the line of 'reload DLL from GAC', so you need to restart it manually.

Comment: Thank you Pieter. Is there any way to show the dialog other than Add Generated Items in the Biztalk project in Visual Studio? You know I am trying to develop and see the results after building. Its weird to restart VS every time I make a change.

Comment: Not that I know of I'm afraid.